# Variable constants in PHP

Tags: php, variables, constants

Is it possible to change the value of a constant in PHP? We want sensible defaults for the configuration files for our project.

Currently we are doing:

config.php:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', '/home/user/public_html');
```

config.default.php:

```
defined('WEB_ROOT') || define('WEB_ROOT', '/home/user/public_html');
```

The problem is that in certain cases, you may want to access certain configuration defaults from inside 'config.php'. For example:

config.php

```
define('USER_FILE_ROOT', WEB_ROOT.'/files');
```

The scheme with constants for configuration has been used for 5 years, and rewriting the framework is not an option.

Comment: Constants are supposed to be... well... [***constant***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constant).There's no such thing as a "variable constant". In other words, you want a constant to be a variable? That makes no sense to me. Why not just use a variable instead?

Comment: If you want to change value, use variable. That's what it's for. You can make it in $ALL_CAPS to look more like global constant, if you wish

Comment: Using constants for a dynamic configuration is a bad idea. Use arrays.

Comment: Turns out that PHP allows "redeclaring" a constant once, and the question is not about whether or not the idea is good nor is it a question about alternatives. The framework has tens of thousands of lines of code that relies on constants. Can't rewrite everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can!

First declare the defaults like this:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', '/var/www', TRUE);
```

Then include the config file:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', '/home/user/public_html');
```

This code works well:

```
define('FOO', 'BAR', TRUE);
echo FOO; // outputs BAR
define('FOO', 'FOOBAR');
echo FOO; // outputs FOOBAR
```

This is a side effect of the incredible fact that PHP supports declaring case insensitive constants.

Comment: This is not "redefine". This relies on fact, that case-insensitive constants are stored in _lower_ case. So is you'll do `echo foo` you'll see `"BAR"`. So it's a tricky way to confuse code reader. I definitely do not recommend to do such thing. Besides, you'll not be able to do this thing more than once.

Comment: Actually, you can "redeclare" lower case constants as well - the fact that constants are stored lower case internally is not exposed to the developer. And the use case I specified only requires doing it once.

Comment: It has nothing to do with re-declaring. It is declaring of two different constants - but in twisted way (which may confuse person who reads the code). Constants can not (and should not) be re-declared by definition.

Comment: Anyway you see it, I achieved my goal. What is wrong here is the fact that PHP has a concept of optionally case insensitive constants. You are claiming one should not utilize that feature, but in this case the other alternative would have been to rewrite tens of thousands of lines of code to use variables for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's a constant, and by definition you shouldn't be able to redefine it. The problem lies in your code logic if you ended up needing to redefine it.

But if you still want to go on that path you can use [runkit_constant_redefine](http://sg.php.net/runkit_constant_redefine)

Comment: Configuration files aren't code logic. But it is nice to be able to access the config defaults from within the config file. I'd say it is bad design to use variables for configuration, since they can be changed during runtime, which is the reason we designed the framework to use constants initially.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with default constants by using the following pattern:

config.default.php

```
class Config_Defaults{
    const WEB_ROOT = '/home/user/public_html';
}
```

config.myenvironment.php

```
class Config extends Config_Defaults {
    const WEB_ROOT = '/var/www';
}
```

Imho, using a Config-Class to group global constants is always a good idea. An extended class is a clean way to have some reasonable defaults.