# I am able to change the constant value using define method. How to overcome this issue...?

Tags: php, constants

If I pass the optional third parameter in DEFINE method as TRUE, it is allowing me to override the existing value of a constant. This is not the expected behavior as constant's value should not be changed once it is declared.

**Test script:**

```
define("GREETING", "Hello you.",true); 
echo "before changing the constant value "; 
echo GREETING;  // outputs "Hello you."

define("GREETING", "sample value.");
echo GREETING; // outputs "sample value."
```

**Expected result:**

> constant's value should not be changed once it is declared.

**Actual result:**

> it is allowing me to override the existing value of a constant.

Comment: Ok, SET it to FALSE. What's the problem then?

Comment: "This is not the expected behavior as constant's value should not be changed once it is declared." Who told You that it should not be redefinable??

Comment: Please go through the below link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225980/variable-constants-in-php

Comment: Why in the Earth are you trying to re-define constant? If you need something mutable, use _variables_. Constant is immutable _by definition_

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are not re-declaring the `CONSTANT`, instead when you declare a constant with the third `boolean true` for case-insensitivity then the constant you declare gets declared in lower case behind the scene, so for example:

```
define("GREETING", "Hello you.",true);
```

Internally it was defined in `lowercase` and when you are again defining:

```
define("GREETING", "Hello you.");
```

It's now defined in `UPPERCASE` (default) so you have two different constants and they are:

```
greeting // first one because of "true" but we don't see it
GREETING // second one
```

As a proof, you can't re-declare the same constant twice using `true`, for example:

```
define("GREETING", "Hello you.",true); 
echo "before changing the constant value <br />"; 
echo GREETING;
define("GREETING", "sample value.", true);
echo GREETING;
```

**Output (Same):**

```
before changing the constant value 
Hello you.Hello you.
```

**About the case_insensitive parameter:**

> If set to TRUE, the constant will be defined
>   case-insensitive. The default behavior is case-sensitive; i.e.
>   CONSTANT and Constant represent different values.

So, a `CONSTANT` is not changeable and it's always a `CONSTANT` as it's name says. Read the manual ([User Contributed Notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)).

Comment: I guess in the "proof" the first *define* should not have *true*...

Answer (score 0):

Write a function

```
function myDefine((string) $name, $value, $ignoreCase = false) {
    if (!isset({$name}) {
       define($name,$value,$ignoreCase);
    } else {
       throw new Exception("constant's value should not be changed once it is declared.");
    }
}
```

If isset() won't work try empty().

Comment: you have "$ingnoreCase" then you changed to "$ignoreCase"

Comment: When you ignore case, you also cannot guarantee, that `!isset({$name})` will detect a defined constant

Comment: so do the double check - && !isset({strtolower($name)})